# PHP doesn't take selected option value on post

Tags: php, html, select

Well i have a serious problem on updating a form, it only takes the selected value on user action in the select option menu but when the user updates the data without changing the select value it returns the default database value which is set to 0

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="socio_demo_type" id="socio_demo_type">
<?php
$query_sd = "SELECT * FROM insertion WHERE id_insertion = ".$insertion["id"];
$result_sd = mysql_query($query_sd);
$type = mysql_fetch_array($result_sd);
$val = $type["ciblage_socio_demo_type"];
?>
    <option value="0"  <?php if($val == 0) echo 'selected' ?> >Pack affinitaire </option>  
    <option value="1"  <?php if($val == 1) echo 'selected' ?> >Achat ciblé (loggué)`enter code here`</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Then you have to validate it before using it. If its wrong you have to put the user back to the data entry page and give them an error message

Comment: No i'm not new in **php** , this is an old application coded in 2005 and we must do some changes on some bugs found ... :/

Comment: @RiggsFolly they're using modals and i can't even use print_r to show post value or debug

Comment: Did you try outputing debug info to a file instead of to the screen

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can i do that ?

Comment: Whatever you want to echo, you use file_put_contents like `file_put_contents('debug.txt', print_r($xxx,true), FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: Or use `error_log()` like `error_log(print_r($_POST,1), 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");`

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok i'll try it thanks dude :)

Comment: Did you solve this? Where does `$val` come from in this code? It's not clear how you choose the value in the first place. That's likely to be the key to the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Pass the connection sting as well and use my sqli statements.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }    

<select class="selectpicker" name="socio_demo_type" id="socio_demo_type">

    <?php

    $query_sd = "SELECT * FROM insertion WHERE id_insertion = "$insertion["id"];

    $result_sd = mysqli_query($con , $query_sd);
    $type = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sd);
    $val = $type["ciblage_socio_demo_type"];

    ?>
    <option value="0"  <?php if($val == 0) echo 'selected' ?> > Option2 </option>  
    <option value="1"  <?php if($val == 1) echo 'selected' ?> > Option1 </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you going somewhere with this? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Dude, the OP is using the old `mysql_` database extension, because he is maintaining some OLD CODE :) Its always a good idea to check the comments before trying to answer

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors - additionally, you should highlight which changes are important such that others can learn from your code

Comment: Dude i'm calling mysql connection on a single file on the top of my page